# How to properly clean up JDBC resources in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc

What is considered best practices when cleaning up JDBC resources and why? I kept the example short, thus just the cleaning up of the ResultSet.

```
finally
{
  if(rs != null)
    try{ rs.close(); } catch(SQLException ignored) {}
}
```

versus

```
finally
{
  try{ rs.close(); } catch(Exception ignored) {}
}
```

Personally I favour the second option since it is a bit shorter. Any input on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Never tought about the second option - it can be useful for closing streams as well. BTW - I like your name for the `ignored` exception and will keep that in mind :-)

Comment: Anyway, forget about "keeping the example short" :-)

Comment: I would recommend Vickie's reply below.  It is never really good practice to expect an exception to be thrown as part of the normal flow of code.  In your second, preferred block, you're relying on the exception to handle the case of a null ResultSet instead of checking it yourself.

Answer (score 11):

Nowadays JDK 7 gives you the easiest option to clean up resources:

```
String query = "select COF_NAME, PRICE from COFFEES";
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
        float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
        System.out.println(coffeeName + ", "  + price);
    }
}
```

The try statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, JDBC resources (statements, result sets, etc...) are rarely `null`. If they are, you have *bigger* issues on your hands than `NullPointerException`s. In that regard, the `NullPointerException`s will help alert you to severe problems with your JDBC driver. The typical checking for `null` before calling `close()` would silently hide the problem if your JDBC driver was, in fact, providing you with `null` references.

As well, not all JDBC drivers follow the specification precisely. For example, some drivers will not automatically close a `ResultSet` when it's associated `Statement` is closed. Therefore, you have to ensure that *you* explicitly close both the `ResultSet` **and** its `Statement` (sigh).

In practice, I have found this technique useful (although its not the prettiest):

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("...");
try {
    ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
    try {
        while (results.next()) {
            // ...
        }
    } finally {
        results.close();
    }
} finally {
    statement.close();
}
```

This technique guarantees that every `close()` statement is executed, starting with the `ResultSet` and working its way outward. `NullPointerException`s are still thrown should the driver provide you with `null` references, but I allow this for the reasons explained at the beginning. `SQLException`s are still thrown if any of the `close()` statements fail (I consider this a good thing - I want to know if something is going wrong).

Comment: Of course you can hide this with the Execute Around idiom. Or use an ORM.

Comment: @Tom: True. I rather like Spring's `JdbcTemplate` for this type of stuff. Although, truth be told, I actually *like* the syntax in my answer (I claim "it's not the prettiest" based on opinions I have heard from others). I find it beautiful in its simplicity and structure. Strange, but true.

Comment: How do you handle SQLExceptions thrown by close() methods?

Comment: @André: I purposely don't handle those `SQLException`s because I prefer to know if the driver is experiencing trouble. It's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

I see no problem with your second (uncommon) version.

- usually, rs will not be `null`, so an NPE will occur in rare cases. So I see no performance problem here.
- both version behave exactly the same in case of `rs = null`

The only disadvantage - if we have more then one resource to close, then we'd have to add one try/catch for each resource, if we want to close as many resources as possible. Otherwise, we'd enter the catch clause with the first `null` and that could cause undiscored leaks.

So it would look like that:

```
finally {
   try{rs.close();  }catch(Exception ignored){}
   try{stmt.close();}catch(Exception ignored){}
   try{conn.close();}catch(Exception ignored){}
}
```

... which is still readable and understandable. But, according to *never change a common pattern* - I'd stick to the old-fashioned way of testing `null` first and catching `SQLException` while closing.

Comment: +1 for not doing something stupid with `null`s. -1 for your exception handling, **and for appearing a bit confused as to how three locals will have been initialised**.

Comment: @Tom - this is just an assessment of the consequences implied by the OPs suggestion (version 2). Thought it would be clear enough...

Comment: Even if it were okay to overlook such crimes, you have coalesced `finally` blocks. `finally` blocks do not coaslesce.

Comment: that's exactly how I do it. I don't do any logging in the 'finally' catch blocks. I tend to add the logging in the catch blocks just before the finally block.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use the following approach. I think it is good to check for `null` because it shows your intent i.e. that you do realise that these objects could be null in rare cases. (A null check is also faster than the creation of a `NullPointerException`.) I also think it is good to log the exceptions, instead of swallowing them. In the cases where `close` fails, I want to know about it and have it in my log files.

```
finally {            
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                 LOG.warn("Failed to close rs", e);
                }
            }
            if (st != null) {
                try {
                    st.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) { 
                 LOG.warn("Failed to close st", e);     
                }
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                 LOG.warn("Failed to close conn", e);
                }
            }
        }
```

If you are going to be doing this frequently, instead of copying and pasting this code over and over again, create a utility class with static methods to close the ResultSet, Statement and Connection.

With [DBUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) you can perform this cleanup quite concisely as follows:

```
 finally {            
            DBUtils.closeQuietly(rs);
            DBUtils.closeQuietly(st);
            DBUtils.closeQuietly(conn);            
        }
```

Comment: Oh dear. Something daft with `null`s and swallowing exceptions.

Comment: This is brilliant solution as Tom stated thats a check for null is cheaper than throwing a NullPointerException. Logging is optional in my opinion, especially by a close. Who cares if it fails to close,  if it was no successful then odds are your pooling is not going to reuse the connection anyway etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void close(Statement... statements) {
        for (Statement stmt : statements) {
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
            }// nothing we can do
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection conn) {
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
        }// nothing we can do
    }
public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            if (rs != null) 
                rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
        }// nothing we can do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach for JDK 6. If you have JDK 7+ you better use the approach I describe here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9200053/259237

```
private void querySomething() {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        // get connection
        // prepare statement
        // execute query
        // and so on
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new MyException("Error while talking to database", e);
    } finally {
        close(connection, statement, rs);
    }
}

// useful because you probably have more than one method interacting with database
public static void close (Connection connection, Statement statement, ResultSet rs) {
    if (rs != null) {
        try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) { _logger.warning(e.toString()); }
    }
    if (statement != null) {
        try { statement.close(); } catch (Exception e) { _logger.warning(e.toString()); }
    }
    if (connection != null) {
        try { connection.close(); } catch (Exception e) { _logger.warning(e.toString()); }
    }
}
```

- It's short.
- It defines a close method that can be statically imported.
- It avoids empty catch blocks.
- It handles any SQLException that may occur (even in getConnection or close methods).
- It's null-safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
ResultSet rs = //initialize here
try {
  // do stuff here
} finally {
  try { rs.close(); }
  catch(SQLException ignored) {}
}
```

Comment: What happens if your ResultSet initialization returns an error (in case of a misconfigured or unresponsive database)?

Comment: @Jean what should happen? It doesn't need to be closed in that case.

Comment: +1 for not doing something stupid with `null`s. -1 for your exception handling.

Comment: @Tom it is not my exception handling :) The post just avoids treating NPE and SQLExceptions in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a long running application you should consider connection pooling.

The Apache DBCP project does a lot of this work for you. You could also look at something like Spring JDBC or Hibernate as well.

The Spring stuff uses object pooling and adds some really nice methods for abstracting away JDBC nastiness.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question? If using database connection pooling, it becomes even *more* important to be sure you close all the resources (statements and result sets) created by the current connection so you don't put a dirty connection back into the pool.

Comment: fair point about DBCP - you do still need to clean up. But combine it with the Spring framework (using the JDBCTemplate) and you can remove a lot of boiler plate code.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void closeAll(){
        closeResultSet();
        closeStatement();
        closeConnection();
    }   

protected void closeConnection(){
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                /*Logger*/
            }
            connection = null;
        }
    }


    protected void closeStatement() {
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                ocstmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                /*Logger*/
            }
            ocstmt = null;
        }
    }


    protected void closeResultSet() {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                /*Logger*/
            }
            rs = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use Logger before closing each. I assume you know this but one more time http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html

Comment: -1 Worst yet. `null` silliness. Swallowing exceptions. And a lack of `finally`.

Comment: Item 7: Avoid Finalizers (Effective Java)

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=effective+java&hl=en&src=bmrr&ei=_N8RTeL8Jo_rOfrq5N8I&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I know it is differ from final and thanks to your for(;;){print('!')}

Comment: @hilal: I believe Tom misspelled `finally` when he said "Finalisers are a completely different thing to `final`!!!!!!!111!1!!". You responded by saying that you "know it is differ from final". Just so we're clear, do you know the difference between *finalizers* and *`finally`*? I'm a bit confused by the conversation. :)

Comment: @Tom agression never give results

Comment: I just just want to show that Java architects avoid from using finally. Anyway, I commented too much. sorry for that, my friends

Comment: @hilal: I think you are a little confused. *Finalizers* are when you override the `finalize()` method of the `Object` class. They are considered bad because you're not guaranteed they will ever be called. However, `finally` statements are part of the try/catch statement that Java experts use regularly. Their names are similar, so they're easy to confuse.

Comment: @hilal putting the code to clean up in separate methods is ok but I would rather spend my time implementing the template method pattern.