# How to call Stored Procedure and prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc, db2

In the below code I want to call one stored procedures and execute one Query. I am facing error at `statement.executeUpdate();` Please help in fixing it. I am not sure where it going wrong.

```
public void Dbexe() {

    Connection connection;
    connection = DatabaseConnection.getCon();
     CallableStatement stmt;
    try {
        stmt = connection.prepareCall("{CALL optg.Ld_SOpp}");
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

     System.out.println("Stored Procedure executed");

     //PreparedStatement statement = null;
    // ResultSet rs = null;

    try{


     PreparedStatement statement;
    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement("MERGE INTO OPTG.R_VAL AS TARGET USING" + 
              ........... +
             "");

         statement.executeUpdate(); //Here the exception is thrown  
         statement.close();

         connection.commit();
         connection.close();


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    // statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

     //statement.close();

    }

    finally{

        System.out.println("Data is copied to the  Table");

            }    

 }
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in the sql sentence you're trying to execute. I mean, is an error from DB2, not java. Probably we gonna need the whole sql statement to identify where the error is.

Comment: Hi, U r right.. the problem was in Query. I corrected. Thank u.

Answer (score 5):

Little off-topic: You should use `CallableStatement` instead if you want to call a store procedure (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html)):

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call opptymgmt.Load_SiebelOpportunity}");
ResultSet rs = callableStatement.executeQuery();
```

I would also suggest you check this topic [How to properly clean up JDBC resources in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508172/how-to-properly-clean-up-jdbc-resources-in-java). It was very helpful to me.

**Update**: based on this stack trace:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mo: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=MERGE INTO OPPTYMGMT.REVENUE_VALIDAT;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<variable_set>, DRIVER=4.7.85
```

The problem seems to be in the sql sentence you're trying to execute. I mean, is an error from DB2, not java. You should check your sql statement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Im getting error at  statement.executeUpdate();

Comment: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mo: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=MERGE INTO OPPTYMGMT.REVENUE_VALIDAT;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<variable_set>, DRIVER=4.7.85

Comment: Can u please check whether I have closed connection, callablestatement, prepared statments properly or not?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in this method:

```
 PreparedStatement myStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
    myStmt.setInt(1, id); //position of parameter (1,2,3....) , value
    
     ResultSet rs = myStmt.executeQuery();
       
    while (rs.next()) {
        int jobId = rs.getInt("jobId"); ....... }
```